# How to change the isolation level of a transaction in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, transactions

When I use `$this->db->trans_start();` in CodeIgniter, it starts a transaction with the read committed isolation level. I want to use the serializable isolation level instead, but `trans_start` doesn’t seem to allow me to set this.

How do I set the transaction level of a transaction in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` in a query right after the start of the transaction:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;');
```

Answer (score -1):

according to [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html)

I think you should use `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` if you want to do it during the transaction

or else

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` and set it **before** starting the transaction like this:

```
$this->db->query('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;');
$this->db->trans_start();
```

Here's a copy paste from the docs:

> With the GLOBAL keyword, the statement sets the default transaction
>   level globally for all subsequent sessions. Existing sessions are
>   unaffected.
>
> With the SESSION keyword, the statement sets the default transaction
>   level for all subsequent transactions performed within the current
>   session.
>
> Without any SESSION or GLOBAL keyword, the statement sets the
>   isolation level for the next (not started) transaction performed
>   within the current session.
>
> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL without GLOBAL or SESSION is not
>   permitted while there is an active transaction

Comment: I tried both ways and setting it **before** the transaction didn't work for me. Maybe the transaction starts a new session?
Setting it just **after** starting the transaction worked fine, using SET SESSION.